# Copy and paste value to a destination

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm copying data from one sheet with yesterday's information to another sheet with a table of historical data. The first sheet is actually a vlookup formula, so I need to only paste the value to the historical table.  This is what I wrote, but it's saying that the last line doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()
'
' UpdateTablesAndCharts Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+t
'


Dim lngNextEmptyRow As Long
Dim lngLastImportRow As Long
Dim shtYstrdy As Worksheet
Set shtYstrdy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yesterday")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ICT Historical Crashlytics Data")
lngNextEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Rows(lngNextEmptyRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
.Cells(lngNextEmptyRow, "A").Value2 = _
    .Cells(lngNextEmptyRow - 1, "A").Value2 + 1
shtYstrdy.Range("AM1:AN1").Copy
    Cells("A" & lngNextEmptyRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Cells() format is `Cells(Rows,Column)` You probably want Range().
2. When just pasting the values it is faster to just assign it directly.
3. The Cells() was missing the `.` in front so it was not assigned to the proper parent sheet.

Use this:

```
Sub Test()
'
' UpdateTablesAndCharts Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+t
'


Dim lngNextEmptyRow As Long
Dim lngLastImportRow As Long
Dim shtYstrdy As Worksheet
Set shtYstrdy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yesterday")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ICT Historical Crashlytics Data")
    lngNextEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Rows(lngNextEmptyRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Cells(lngNextEmptyRow, "A").Value2 = _
        .Cells(lngNextEmptyRow - 1, "A").Value2 + 1
    .Range("A" & lngNextEmptyRow).Resize(1, 2).Value = shtYstrdy.Range("AM1:AN1").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not taking that last line. What does Resize do?

Comment: I do not get that mine compiles just fine. Did you copy and paste everything?  Are you sure you got the whole line and replaced all the correct lines?

Comment: I think it's because I didn't add the space between 1, and 2. it just worked.

Comment: @EmmaTucker feel free to mark as correct, by clicking the check mark by the answer.